# Such as the Dart iscroll to implement scrolling would like to know what to do.

Tags: scroll, dart

Such as the Dart iscroll to implement scrolling would like to know what to do. 
Darts scrolling in the editor, but the packages are supported by 
I do not know how to use the module for that. 
I hope you'll tell you how to scroll.

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. Can you explain a bit more or provide a link to where we can see what you want to do.

Comment: Maybe something like this http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5. I have no idea if something like this is available for Dart. Maybe the JS version can also be used in a Dart application (as long as there is no Polymer/ShadowDOM involved).

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tour.  You have no clear question, but it sounds like you are having trouble scrolling using Dart.  Please share with us your code that is not working, and describe what you want to happen, and what happens that you don't like.

Comment: My question is, literally. 
Pubspec.yaml practicing darts through the Dependencies editor to add to the scrolling. 
I would like to know how to use the scrolling. 
Scrolling with two iscroll I would like to know if you have the same effect. 

Required to report not knowing how to write values ​​into the source I saw.

Comment: _scroller = new PositionScroller (ulList, verticalScroll: _vertical, horizontalScroll: _horizontal, duration: 50, easing: Easing.CUBIC_EASY_IN_OUT) 
   .. scroll (); 

However, because in this way does not scroll. 

More detailed questions should do at some point, Chris? 
I want to add an image to image will not go up.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445809 (where he asked again)